# multiple mysql query and callback in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have code  like that  but callback doesn't work. All querys work, console.log writes  row id.  Queries are dependent

```
exports.order_taxometr = function (data, client, callback) {
    db.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
      db.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
         db.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
            db.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
                console.log(rows[0].id);
                res[order] = rows;
                res['result'] = "success";
                res['message'] = "ok";
                callback(res);
              })
         })
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: do you have an error ? what is `res` ? is `order` initialized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.query(sql, function (err, rows1) {
  db.query(sql, function (err, rows2) {
    db.query(sql, function (err, rows3) {
      db.query(sql, function (err, rows4) {
        var result = {};
        var res = {};
        var order = {};
        result["firstROW"] = rows1;
        result["secondROW"] = rows2;
        result["forthROW"] = rows3;
        result["fifthtROW"] = rows4;
        res[order] = result;
        res['result'] = "success";
        res['message'] = "ok";
        callback(res);
        db.close();
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: This code was very useful to me. I just declare variables as an array and add ';'.

Comment: Only code answers are generally consiedered as low-quality answers. You should provide some details in the answer. You can add your comment to your answer

Comment: Answering questions is good, thank you. However, this answer is very similar to that written by @MuhammadAli. A code-only answer that is almost identical to another older answer is not very useful unless the new answer explains how is it useful and how it improves upon that other answer. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The result of all queries are in same variable , they will overright last variable

```
   db.query(sql, function (err, rows1) {
     db.query(sql, function (err, rows2) {
        db.query(sql, function (err, rows3) {
           db.query(sql, function (err, rows4) {
               var result = {};
               var res = {};
               var order = {};
               result["firstROW"] = rows1;
               result["secondROW"] = rows2;
               result["forthROW"] = rows3;
               result["fifthtROW"] = rows4;

              res[order] = result;
              res['result'] = "success";
              res['message'] = "ok";
              callback(res);
             })
         })
        })
      })
   }
```

Comment: No,  second query using first query results, third using 2 nd results, i want get result of lastest,    but on my example callback doesn't work